# About sites for amateur writers

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, websites

Are there any websites were an amateur writer can post a story or parts of a story and for a fee or for free the writing will be posted for a 'while'? (And maybe the story will be 'noticed' by a publisher.)

Comment: I was told by a friend that she was approached by an agent because the agent read stories my friend had posted in a writer's forum. I also know that agents and publishers watch writing contests (or set up their own contests). What the best opportunities are will change with country, genre, and time (because once a forum is known for visiting agents, it will overflow with the same trash that they already have on their slush pile, and the agents will move on).

Comment: What are the best amateur-writer forums websites? Do you know any such addresses?

Comment: Not for English. I'm German, and so is my friend.

Comment: Check out OpenBook.pub. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I will take note of this. Great suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of http://www.writersbeat.com myself. The site itself is a forum, and you'll be able to publish parts or complete stories while getting loads of great feedback. A very helpful and friendly community.

I don't know if there are actual agents or publishers lurking there, but it's quite large so I would not be surprised.

OpenBook.pub as Ivo suggested is also a nice site.